# Update AWS Task definition.json file from jenkins file dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS ECS task definition.json file in Gitlab repo and i am calling the same from my jenkins file to create new task definition.

All the content in the task definition file i.e. container definitions details are hard coded. But I want the docker image path from ECR to be passed dynamically to the same.

Can anybody please help me with the same.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to pre-process you json file before pushing itto AWS. You can use `sed` to replace placeholders or default values with values for curent pipeline - it should be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need two steps

- Create new revision
- Add new task definition against above revision

> But I want the docker image path from ECR to be passed dynamically to the same.

The below script will do exactly what you are looking for, all you need to define or replace these ENV

```
TAG="BUILD_NUMBER"
NODE_ENV="development"
AWSREGION="us-west-2"
```

Create `revision.sh`

```
# task defintion dyanmic variable
TAG="BUILD_NUMBER"
NODE_ENV="development"
AWSREGION="us-west-2"

# Creae new revesion

NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=$(echo `cat <<EOF
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 3000,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 3000
      }
    ],
    "environment":
        [
            {
                "name": "NODE_ENV",
                "value":"$NODE_ENV"
            }
        ],
    "ulimits": [
        {
          "name": "nofile",
          "softLimit": 65536,
          "hardLimit": 95536
        }
     ],
    "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
         "awslogs-group": "${ENV}_nodejs",
        "awslogs-region": "$AWSREGION",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
       }
      },
    "memoryReservation": 500,
    "image": "1234.dkr.ecr.${AWSREGION}.amazonaws.com/test/nodejs:${TAG}",
    "name": "$ENV-nodejs"

  }
],
"family": "$ENV-nodejs"
}
EOF`
)
    echo "New Revesion"
    echo "${NEW_TASK_DEFINITION}" | python -m json.tool

#####################
#####Step 2#########
# Registering New Task Definition, 
aws ecs register-task-definition --region ${AWSREGION} --cli-input-json "$NEW_TASK_DEFINITION"
```

If you want to call it this script from pipeline then you need to make these changes.

```
# task defintion dyanmic variable
TAG="${1}"
NODE_ENV="${2}"
AWSREGION="${3}"
.
.
.
```

so to call this script

```
./update_task.sh build_tag development us-west-2
```

Comment: Thanks, so you are suggesting i create this shell script file in my git branch and call it from my jenkins pipeline script and pass on the parameters to it dynamically, is that correct.

Comment: yes its correct, but you will need to make a little bit changes if call that as as script

Comment: I update the question accordingly to work with Jenkins file.

Comment: Thank you.. can you please tell how can i call the revision.sh file in gitlab from my inline pipeline script in jenkins or from the jenkis file,

Comment: I'm not sure about gitlib, but as there way tu pass environment variables from gitlib?

Answer (score 0):

The overall approach described by @Adiii it's ok, as soon as the Docker image from ECR is the only thing changing on every deployment. Please, remember to [force a new deployment afterwards](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html), with:

```
aws ecs update-service --force-new-deployment # ... cluster and service here
```

Just for sharing, see also [ecs-deploy](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy) and [yoke](https://github.com/GuccioGucci/yoke), in case you're looking for some reusable component. They're also supporting changing the task-definition, such as for new environment variables. The latter (which I'm contributing to) would also make it per-environment, with a proper template engine.